# Fetching JSON data from a url through PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use php to make a currency converter. However as you see, everything works if I locally download the JSON, re-structure it and call it through `file_get_contents()`.

JSON:

```
{"status":true,"data":[{"buy_rate":"19.00","sell_rate":"19.20","currency":"China Yuan","flagicon":"CN","countrycode":"CNY"},{"buy_rate":"1.13","sell_rate":"1.14","currency":"Japanese Yen","flagicon":"jp","countrycode":"JPY"},{"buy_rate":"166.00","sell_rate":"167.65","currency":"UK Pound Sterling","flagicon":"GB","countrycode":"GBP"},{"buy_rate":"33.70","sell_rate":"34.05","currency":"Saudi Riyal","flagicon":"SA","countrycode":"SAR"},{"buy_rate":"93.75","sell_rate":"94.70","currency":"Australian Dollar","flagicon":"AU","countrycode":"AUD"},{"buy_rate":"34.50","sell_rate":"34.85","currency":"U.A.E Dirham","flagicon":"AE","countrycode":"AED"},{"buy_rate":"96.00","sell_rate":"96.95","currency":"Canadian Dollar","flagicon":"ca","countrycode":"CAD"},{"buy_rate":"129.50","sell_rate":"130.80","currency":"US Dollar","flagicon":"us","countrycode":"USD"},{"buy_rate":"148.00","sell_rate":"149.50","currency":"Euro","flagicon":"eu","countrycode":"EUR"},{"buy_rate":"1.00","sell_rate":"1.00","currency":"Pakistani Rupee","flagicon":"pk","countrycode":"PKR"}]}
```

Code:

```
 <?php

    $url = 'list.JSON';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $output = json_decode($data);

   foreach ($output as $outputs): ?> 

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $outputs->buy_rate; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $outputs->sell_rate; ?><td>
    <td><?php echo $outputs->currency; ?><td>
    <td><?php echo $outputs->flagicon; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $outputs->countrycode; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should not post your access key online though

Comment: Why did you leave out the `file_get_contents` and `json_decode` code when using the live site? It should work the same as with the local file, just use the `URL` instead of the local `URI`

Comment: Where is your fetching code ? what is `$output` ?

Comment: @DarkBee this is the fetching code:

   <?php
 
 $url = 'list.JSON';
 $data = file_get_contents($url);
 $output = json_decode($data);
?>

Comment: Replace `URL` with the direct `URL` to the data and it should work (if you have the setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) enabled)

Comment: Thank you but how do I enable the setting llow_url_fopen

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is enabled by default, see if it works, if it doesn't, change it in your `php.ini` file. Restart your server afterwards. Notice how `allow_url_fopen` is linked in DarkBee's comment? You can click it

Answer (score 0):

You just have to get the contents via `file_get_contents` (by example) and use
`json_decode`

Here is an example:

```
//this url is random
$content = file_get_contents('http://myjsondata.com');
//Decode json output to object 
$output = json_decode($content);
//parse your object like you want
//I assume that my json contain a key 'data' HERE !
foreach($output->data as $data) {
     //Do what you want here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I agree but I tried this method before by simply replacing file name with url. However as you see, my json is troubling me.

Comment: your Json fits exactly my example, your data  are stored in the key `data`.